# How to select multiple items from a table based on certain cumulative amount?

Tags: mysql

I have a table name "foods", there have various foods with different calories. For example bellow:

Table: foods

```
id    name      calories
-----------------------
1     beef      200
2     tomato    400
3     carrot    500
4     nuts      800
```

what I want: I want to select multiple foods from the table based on calorie amount when the sum of callories reach to a certain amount, I want to stop query there and echo the result. For example, when I will want 600 calories, result will show for the first two food 200+400=600. when I will want calorie limit will be 1000, it will take any two or more foods those calories amount reach to 1000 or near 1000.
I have tried with following code to make it ; but it does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM foods WHERE SUM(calories)=1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable in order to calculate cumulative sum:

```
SELECT id, name, calories
FROM (
   SELECT id, name, calories,
          @cumSum:= @cumSum + calories AS cumSum
   FROM foods, (SELECT @cumSum:=0) var
   ORDER BY id ) t
WHERE cumSum <= 600
```

The subquery calculates the cumulative sum and stores its value in `@cumSum` variable. The outer query can then use calculated column `cumSum` to filter out results having a cumulative sum greater than 600.

**Output:**

```
id  name    calories
----------------------
1   beef    200
2   tomato  400
```

[**Fiddle Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87ec7/2)